Change entry point in Expo (react-native) application cause fatal crash
I have upgraded my old Expo application from SDK 47 to SDK 51.
in the package.json I have "main":"./index.js", and the index.js looks like
import { registerRootComponent } from "expo";
import App from "./App";

registerRootComponent(App);

Running expo run:android the app crashes with
08-29 18:14:55.167  4720  4720 E AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-29 18:14:55.167  4720  4720 E AndroidRuntime: Process: com.expoplayground, PID: 4720
08-29 18:14:55.167  4720  4720 E AndroidRuntime: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to create application com.expoplayground.MainApplication: java.lang.IllegalStateException: DevelopmentClientController was initialized.
08-29 18:14:55.167  4720  4720 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:6764)
08-29 18:14:55.167  4720  4720 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.ActivityThread.-$$Nest$mhandleBindApplication(Unknown Source:0)
08-29 18:14:55.167  4720  4720 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2133)
08-29 18:14:55.167  4720  4720 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
08-29 18:14:55.167  4720  4720 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:201)
08-29 18:14:55.167  4720  4720 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:288)
08-29 18:14:55.167  4720  4720 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7872)
08-29 18:14:55.167  4720  4720 E AndroidRuntime:    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
08-29 18:14:55.167  4720  4720 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:548)

This is the complete MainActivity.kt
package com.expoplayground

import android.os.Build
import android.os.Bundle

import com.facebook.react.ReactActivity
import com.facebook.react.ReactActivityDelegate
import com.facebook.react.defaults.DefaultNewArchitectureEntryPoint.fabricEnabled
import com.facebook.react.defaults.DefaultReactActivityDelegate

import expo.modules.ReactActivityDelegateWrapper

class MainActivity : ReactActivity() {
  override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    setTheme(R.style.AppTheme);
    super.onCreate(null)
  }

  /* It should return "main" https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/register-root-component/#manual-android-setup */
  override fun getMainComponentName(): String = "main"

  override fun createReactActivityDelegate(): ReactActivityDelegate {
    return ReactActivityDelegateWrapper(
          this,
          BuildConfig.IS_NEW_ARCHITECTURE_ENABLED,
          object : DefaultReactActivityDelegate(
              this,
              mainComponentName,
              fabricEnabled
          ){})
  }

  override fun invokeDefaultOnBackPressed() {
      if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT <= Build.VERSION_CODES.R) {
          if (!moveTaskToBack(false)) {
              super.invokeDefaultOnBackPressed()
          }
          return
      }

      super.invokeDefaultOnBackPressed()
  }
}



Did you follow this document when you upgraded Expo to 51? Especially the part about deprecations, renaming and removals.

There was no specific log to give a little hint of which library conflicts with the new architecture of Expo SDK 51. I had to start from scratch and install libraries one by one and see which one caused the app to crash, which I did not have the time for.
Downgrading to Expo SDK 50.0.20 has solved my issue. and the app works with the specified entry point
